# What is the maximum number of applications that can be activated on the Okta sandbox?

Tags: okta

I am evaluating Okta for SSO and created an account in the sandbox environment (oktapreview.com). After adding 3 applications, the 'Add Application' button is now greyed out.

So, I wanted to check if there is a limit to the number of applications that may be tested in Okta sandbox env? How can I add more apps for testing the SSO configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit on Okta for Developers is 3 apps and 100 users, available forever. If you'd like more apps to test SSO, you can open an Okta for IT account which has unlimited apps and 100 users with a 30 day trial.

https://www.okta.com/start-with-okta/

**Okta for IT**

- Unlimited Applications
- Up to 100 Users
- 30 Day Trial

**Okta for Developers**

- Up to 3 Applications
- Up to 100 Users
- Free Forever